# How to use NTLM authentication from RHEL 8 to RDS for query

Tags: python, sql-server, active-directory, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

I am attempting to connect to a RDS instance that is joined to the AD.

The authentication mechanism it is using is NTLM.

Hence, on my instance where my python web app is hosted, it has to connect to the RDS and authenticate via NTLM with the domain credentials.

I am currently using pyodbc and i have the required msodbcsql drivers as well.

Would appreciate any advice on achieving this.

I have tried using pyodbc to create a connection string.

I have installed the required msodbcsql drivers as well to connect to mssql db hosted on the rds.

Comment: Are you sure it's using NTLM? It's not using Active Directory or Kerberos? Is the instance where the web application hosted also joined to the same domain?

Comment: When i ran this query :
SELECT auth_scheme FROM sys. dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID;|
I add see that the auth_scheme is NTLM.
The instance where the web application hosted is joined to the same domain, able to get a ticket when i kinit then klist following.